# Web Api 2 Attribute Routing, 404 and 405 codes

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I created a testing Web Api 2 in .Net 4.5.2.

The controller code is

```
using System.Web.Http;
using MyService.Models;

namespace MyService.Controllers
{
    public class DefaultController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Members/")]
        public IHttpActionResult CreateRequest(MyRequestDto request)
        {
            return this.Ok();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Members/{id : int}")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetMember(int id)
        {
            var response = new MyRequestDto()
            {
                FirstName = "Test F " + id,
                LastName = "Test L " + id
            };

            return this.Ok(response);
        }
    }
}
```

The web api config code is

```
using System.Web.Http;
using MyService.Infrastructure;

namespace MyService
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            var formatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            formatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I request the services from soapUI I got

- 404 http code for posting some JSON to http://localhost:15945/Members/
- 405 http code for getting from http://localhost:15945/Members/123

It looks like the routing is not working properly. But why?

Comment: please  share RouteConfig !

Comment: @NazmulHasan I use attribute routing, all the codes you need are already in the question.

Answer (score 1):

A couple updates to your Route attributes and you should be fine:

Remove the trailing slash, change `[Route("Members/")]` to `[Route("Members")]`

Remove the spaces, change `[Route("Members/{id : int}")]` to `[Route("Members/{id:int}")]`

You don't need route prefixes, you don't need the tilde in front as the other answers suggest. We have hundreds of routes defined just like this across many different API projects and they work just fine.

The 404 error you are getting is because the trailing slash is part of your route definition, but the actual URI is without the slash even if you include the slash in your request because somewhere in the default asp.net pipeline or even IIS is set to remove the trailing slash. So the actual route never matches your attribute resulting in a 404.

The 405 error you are getting is because the spaces in the route attribute actually messed up the id variable so the route that was getting matched was your POST route and a GET is not allowed resulting in a 405.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but what about declare routing attribute on the class-

something like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class DefaultController : ApiController
```

You got error of 404 or 405 (for post), so that mean that your request didn't reach the web api.

Comment: I try to avoid the prefix. I have some other web api projects without prefix all the routing works.

Answer (score 0):

404

> if the request URI did not match a route for the Web API application, the server would return an HTTP 404 Not Found error.

405

> A request method is not supported for the requested resource; for example, a GET request on a form which requires data to be presented via POST, or a PUT request on a read-only resource.

should be call 
For JSON to `http://localhost:15945/api/Members/` 
For http code for getting from `http://localhost:15945/api/Members/123`

please check this link http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors in your route templates. You should read up some more on [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

Given that here is your fixed controller.

```
public class DefaultController : ApiController
{
    //POST Members
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("~/Members")]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateRequest(MyRequestDto request)
    {
        return this.Ok();
    }

    //GET Members/123
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/Members/{id:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetMember(int id)
    {
        var response = new MyRequestDto()
        {
            FirstName = "Test F " + id,
            LastName = "Test L " + id
        };

        return this.Ok(response);
    }
}
```

Explanation:

Your original prefix for the POST method included a slash with out a parameter so it treated the slash as a literal part of the template.

Your GET method's template had bad syntax `[Route("Members/{id : int}")]` for the `id` parameter. `{id : int}` should not have spaces in the constraint is `{id:int}`.

Comment: I try to avoid the prefix. I have some other web api projects without projects all the routing works.

Comment: with or without that ~/ the result is the same.